# Probability two predictions (from linear model) are different from each other

Tags: probability, estimation, prediction

Suppose I fit a linear model to a bunch of training data and make two out of sample predictions: $P_1 = .5$ with standard error $SE_1 = .08$ and $P_2 = .7$ with standard error $SE_2=.09$.

What is the best way to test if $P_1 \neq P_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question well, this is a classical test for the difference of two proportions. For the simplest way, you may test the null hypothesis $H_0:P_1-P_2=0$ vs $H_1:P_1-P_2\ne0$, such that on the example,

$Z=(P_1-P_2)/\sqrt{SE_1^2+SE_2^2}=0.2/0.1204=1.661 \le 1.96) $

Thus the $H_1$ is failed to be rejected with $\alpha=0.05$ and we conclude that $P_1=P_2$.

Yates' continuity correction may be applied for more accuracy.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was hoping for -- you answer is what I thought of at first, but Googling came up with other somewhat strange answers